# Top of Nautilus window hidden in dual monitor

Tags: nautilus

Recently have this issue when trying to download document using browser (Chrome, Firefox), the nautilus window opened for me to specified the download location. However it got over stretch and the top part is partially hidden when it is opened in one of my monitor screen.

nautilus over-stretch to the top of monitor, the top got partially hidden/blocked
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWmWU.png)

It should look like this
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wvKX.png)

Any idea how we can fix it?

Ubuntu: 20.04.2 LTS
laptop display (the one that has issue): 1440x810
extended display (ok): 1920x1080

Comment: Are you sure the laptop is running at its native screen resolution?

Comment: @Nmath I remembered added one custom resolution to it some time ago. Anyway, just changed to 1280x800(16:10) and 1360x768 from 1440x810, but still having the same issue.

Comment: You should research what is the native resolution and set it to that.  Anything else will look bad on this kind of display.  Can you provide more details and what exactly you did when you added a custom resolution? Maybe something you did is causing this problem.

Comment: @Nmath `xrandr`, then use `cvt` to get the Modeline, and add it with `xrandr --newmode...`, `xrandr --addmode...`. Refer to this page https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/04/custom-screen-resolution-ubuntu-desktop/. But i think it is not permanently applied, as I din add the command to bash init script...

Comment: i search online native resolution for Thinkpad T430 is 1366x768, the closest I got on ubuntu default is 1368x768 or 1360x768